# NX upgrade issue: Cannot load environment variables that do not start with NX_

Tags: environment-variables, nrwl-nx, nx-monorepo

I recently upgraded to the latest version of NX. Previously my backend API apps could read in environment variables regardless of whether they were prefixed with NX_. (e.g `NODE_ENV` or `ORG_HOST_ID`). However, after upgrading, the code only loads environment variables that are prefixed with `NX_` I've tested with different environment files (e.g. at the root and in my specific app folder: `/.env` and `apps/my-app/.env`)

If I have in my `/.env`

```
NODE_ENV=test1
NX_TEST_PROP=test2
```

`NX_TEST_PROP` will be loaded, but not `NODE_ENV`.

Secondly, the code used to be able to programmatically set or override environment variables by doing `process.env[prop]=value`, but now this no longer functions, not even when programmatically setting variables that are prefixed with `NX_`.

(Longer code block:

```js
    // convert key from PascalCase to MACRO_CASE
    const configString = Object.keys(remoteConfig)
      .map((key) => {
        const macroCaseKey = key
          .split(/(?=[A-Z])/)
          .join('_')
          .toUpperCase();
        // If the value is already defined in the master config (e.g. env.production),
        // don't replace it with whatever came from the configuration service
        // need to use the ternary instead of || since the formatting is different when the properties are loaded into process.env vs read in using fs
        process.env[macroCaseKey] = masterEnvConfig[macroCaseKey] ? process.env[macroCaseKey] : remoteConfig[key];
        return `${macroCaseKey}=${remoteConfig[key]}`;
      })
      .join('\n');
```

I've done a fair amount of searching online already, but haven't found anything detailing this being an issue when upgrading.